# Data Science Data Analysis

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, classification, multilabel-classification

I have a dataset with people's characteristics and I need to predict their breakfast [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20KMo.png)'s an example of df.

And I am training cat boost algorithm for that.

Is it possible in my case to predict not only one kind of breakfast, but also an additional one?

By additional I mean the second most appealing type of breakfast for a person.

```py
#I started with this:

df_train, df_test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.15, random_state=42)

df_train, df_valid = train_test_split(df_train, test_size=0.15, random_state=42)

features_train = df_train.drop(\['breakfast'\], axis=1)

target_train = df_train\['breakfast'\]

features_valid = df_valid.drop(\['breakfast'\], axis=1)

target_valid = df_valid\['breakfast'\]

features_test = df_test.drop(\['breakfast'\], axis=1)

target_test = df_test\['breakfast'\]

model_cat = CatBoostClassifier(random_state=42)

model_cat.fit(features_train, target_train)

valid_predictions_tree = model_cat.predict(features_valid)

#But this is supposed to train for a single categorical variable output, however I need not one but two best results.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [predict_proba](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboostclassifier_predict_proba) instead will return the probability for every class of your target:

```py
valid_predictions_tree = model_cat.predict_proba(features_valid)
```

To get clean predictions for an input `dt` you can do this:

```py
proba = pd.DataFrame(model_cat.predict_proba(dt), columns=model_cat.classes_)
```

Output example:

```py
Class1   Class2   Class3
0.2      0.5      0.3
0.7      0.2      0.1
```

The total for each line is 1 (100%).

Comment: You can try `model_cat.predict_proba(dt)` it should return the probability for each class. Then you can select the 2 highest probabilities as #1 and #2 predictions.

Comment: Your last line of code should be `model_cat.predict_proba(dt)`, not `model_cat.predict(dt)`.

Comment: Thank you. That's fair enough

Comment: btw, is there some way to assign the resulting list of probabilities to the corresponding breakfast variables?

Comment: Yes, I edited the answer, you can do `proba = pd.DataFrame(model_cat.predict_proba(dt), columns=model_cat.classes_)` to get a clean table where each column is a class.

Comment: Yeah, that's interesting. I need to remember. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `predict_proba` method to get the 1st and 2nd most probable predictions from the classifier.